# Is it possible to use yolo and OpenCv for annotation

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I want to implement an OCR using python for character recognition, i want to know if is it possible to use  YOLOV3 for extracting features from receipts.

After i asked this question i found a solution of extracting receipt features with VGG16, could you tell me witch is more accurate between them.

Comment: What is TVA?! Besides you want an "annotation tool" or an "OCR algorithm"?

Comment: Sorry i mean VAT, the tax that is added to the price,

Comment: I want to know if i could work with YOLO for receipt and invoice objet detection, if not i need to know witch algorith can i use.

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow. Please see: [help/on-topic], [ask].

Comment: what exactly do you want yolo to do/solve? Detecting individual characters? Derecting an receipt/invoice? Detecting the VAT part?